# R: Problem using dir.create within a For loop

Tags: r, for-loop, directory

I'm building a file directory consisting of a set of folders for years 2023-2030, each containing twelve subfolders (one for every calendar month). The following code correctly prints the file paths I'm trying to create:

```
library(lubridate)

path <- "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/"

for(i in paste0(format(seq(Sys.Date() %m+% years(1), length.out=8, by="+1 years"), "%Y"),"-YTD")) {
  if (!file.exists(paste0(path, i))) {dir.create(path = paste0(path, i))} 
  else {print(paste0(path, i, "/", paste0(format(ISOdate(year(Sys.Date() %m+% years(1)), 1:12, 1), "%m"), "-", month.abb)))}
}

 [1] "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/2023-YTD/01-Jan"
 [2] "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/2023-YTD/02-Feb"
 [3] "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/2023-YTD/03-Mar"
...
[10] "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/2030-YTD/10-Oct"
[11] "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/2030-YTD/11-Nov"
[12] "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/2030-YTD/12-Dec"
```

However, in the `else` section, when I swap the `print` function above for a `dir.create` function, an error message appears:

```
for(i in paste0(format(seq(Sys.Date() %m+% years(1), length.out=8, by="+1 years"), "%Y"),"-YTD")) {
  if (!file.exists(paste0(path, i))) {dir.create(path = paste0(path, i))} 
  else {dir.create(path = paste0(path, i, "/", paste0(format(ISOdate(year(Sys.Date() %m+% years(1)), 1:12, 1), "%m"), "-", month.abb)), showWarnings = FALSE)}
}

Error in dir.create(paste0(paste0(path, i), "/", paste0(format(ISOdate(year(Sys.Date() %m+%  : 
  invalid 'path' argument
```

Why is the error message occurring, and what might I change to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to create two layers of subfolders?  If so, have you added `recursive = TRUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to nest another for loop to create each folder's set:

```
library(lubridate)

path <- "C:/Users/joeshmoe1/Documents/"

for(i in paste0(format(seq(Sys.Date() %m+% years(1), length.out=8, by="+1 years"), "%Y"),"-YTD")) {
 if (!file.exists(paste0(path, i))) {dir.create(path = paste0(path, i))} 
 else {
  for (j in paste0(format(ISOdate(year(Sys.Date() %m+% years(1)), 1:12, 1), "%m"), "-", month.abb)) {
    dir.create(path = paste0(path, i, "/", j))
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! However because of the way my if/else statement is written, this code must be run twice to generate the desired output - once to create the Year folders, then again to create the Month folders inside.

I was able to fix this by copying your nested `for` loop as a second line within the `if` statement, as well as leaving it where it is as the `else` statement.